# tkinter disable canvas not working

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

How do one actually disables a Canvas widget, not just anyone of the objects in it, but the entire Canvas.

The following code attemps to disable the Canvas after clicking it and changing its colour.  But you can see, it can still be clicked and fipping between yellow and black colours.

I would have hoped that after disabling, it'll not respond to any events, and perhaps greying out.

```
import tkinter as tk
w=tk.Tk()

color="yellow"

def flip(a):
    global color
    if color=="yellow": color="black"
    else: color="yellow"
    c.config(bg=color)
    c.config(state="disabled")          # does not work



c=tk.Canvas(w,width=20, height=20, bg=color)
c.place(x=30, y=30)
c.bind("<1>",flip)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested with other widgets and noticed that setting the state to disabled does not disable the bindings. In your case, there are at least two solutions:

- Remove the binding by replacing `c.config(state="disabled")` by `c.unbind('<1>')` at the end of the `flip` function.
- Check the state of the canvas before flipping the color with 
  `if c.cget('state') != 'disabled':`

Comment: Thanks.  I also tried tk.Misc.unbind_all<"1>", which also did not work.  But c.unbind() works.  Thanks

Comment: It did not work because `unbind_all('<1>')` does not unbind '<1>' from all widgets but only the bindings done with `bind_all`.